# Как узнать самое большое число без метода max

Tags: python, list, max

Есть у меня один список из которого нужно найти самое большое число:

```
['138.30000000']
['4312.10000000']
['3552.40000000']
['5635.20000000']
['7185.80000000']
['15925.70000000']
['33492.00000000']
['20641.50000000']
['17632.60000000']
['9450.00000000']
['10699.60000000']
['23726.20000000']
['18398.30000000']
['12293.30000000']
['11432.90000000']
['8325.30000000']
['16084.40000000']
['85679.00000000']
['1648.20000000']
['15038.30000000']
['26279.30000000']
['64136.40000000']
['3284.70000000']
['18593.80000000']
['1758.30000000']
['20301.40000000']
['2953.70000000']
['21084.80000000']
['3919.40000000']
['5869.10000000']
['36933.20000000']
['4818.80000000']
['6291.50000000']
['2243.50000000']
['21265.40000000']
['2446.70000000']
['7180.30000000']
['18564.20000000']
['4001.80000000']
['1528.30000000']
['1855.20000000']
['3404.90000000']
['6807.10000000']
['12609.00000000']
['7920.60000000']
['2212.50000000']
['22546.90000000']
['64413.30000000']
['765.20000000']
['8246.10000000']
['909.80000000']
['22290.50000000']
['2745.60000000']
['14254.70000000']
['5127.50000000']
['10261.80000000']
['1417.60000000']
['75615.30000000']
['2568.70000000']
['28823.30000000']
['656.60000000']
['4514.10000000']
['8239.50000000']
['576.80000000']
['8961.80000000']
['28126.90000000']
['4125.30000000']
['98515.30000000']
['5643.80000000']
['599.00000000']
['1373.90000000']
['1023.60000000']
['2215.50000000']
['8421.10000000']
['8621.20000000']
['2161.70000000']
['787.60000000']
['35686.20000000']
['805.00000000']
['1393.20000000']
['399.80000000']
['1086.30000000']
['3910.60000000']
['9976.10000000']
['1258.00000000']
['2230.30000000']
['17033.10000000']
['40869.70000000']
['1591.70000000']
['30744.40000000']
['1025.00000000']
['14928.60000000']
['4188.60000000']
['802.90000000']
['4623.30000000']
['22987.70000000']
['4054.40000000']
['35458.30000000']
['7787.50000000']
['675.90000000']
['985.70000000']
['2568.10000000']
['1569.60000000']
['1569.20000000']
['1836.50000000']
['690.50000000']
['8067.40000000']
['40683.90000000']
['1263.00000000']
['1063.80000000']
['248.10000000']
['354.00000000']
['1258.70000000']
['266.90000000']
['763.00000000']
['1205.20000000']
['4821.40000000']
['86534.70000000']
['844.40000000']
['359.50000000']
['492.40000000']
['1016.10000000']
['5623.30000000']
['1801.40000000']
['1071.60000000']
['527.10000000']
['2238.90000000']
['42496.80000000']
['2660.50000000']
['1286.10000000']
['5081.40000000']
['1994.70000000']
['3023.50000000']
['1727.70000000']
['866.90000000']
```

И метод `max` мне выдает последнее число в списке. Пытался по другому, не удалось.

Comment: У вас в списках строки. Соответственно, `max` находит наибольшую строку (с лексической точки зрения). Сделайте так, чтобы в списках были числа (или укажите функции `max` параметр `key` с функцией преобразующей строку в число) - будет искать максимальное число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не один список,а много списков, каждый из которых состоит из одного элемента - текстового представления числа с плавающей точкой. Если имелся в виду список вида:

```
['138.30000000', '4312.10000000', ... '866.90000000']
```

тогда без использования метода max:

```
lst = ['138.30000000', '4312.10000000', .... , '866.90000000']

lst = list(map(float,lst))
maximum = lst[0]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    if lst[i] > maximum:
       maximum = lst[i]

print(maximum)
```

Или c max:

```
lst = ['138.30000000', '4312.10000000', .... , '866.90000000']

maximum = max(map(float,lst))
```

или ещё проще c max как советовал GrAnd

```
maximum = max(lst, key=float)
```

Что именно на входе?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем списке хранятся строки. Вам нужно привести все элементы списка к числовому типу.

```
[float(x) for x in list]
```